# Phaser - I Can't start any example

Tags: javascript, frameworks, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

I want to learn this framework ...

I download last version from github put it intro www folder and i don't see any working file .

Is it strict to use MAMP ?

> Being a Unix environment at heart there are more options available on OS X than Windows. But if you'd like an "all in one" approach like WAMP, with a nice clean and easy to use interface, then we'd strongly recommend MAMP. This comes in two versions: one free and one paid for.

Logs :

projects/bomber/

> Viewport argument key "minimal-ui" not recognized and ignored.

This folder should sit along-side the Phaser Examples, for example:

```
/webroot/phaser
/webroot/phaser-examples
```

I use relative path .

Error log from tree examples :

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of
>   404 (Not Found) (phaser.js, line 0)
>   localhost/new_prototype_slot/STARTER/phaser-examples-master/examples/_site/js/phaser.jsFailed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found)

Any suggestion who to start example in localhost !

Answer (score 1):

Download brackets.io text editor, open index.html file, then click "live preview" button?